# how to call both normal dialog and LuisDialog from within the MessageController

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a requirement, where based on some condition I need to call either a normal dialog or a `LuisDialog`, I am unable to achieve the same.

```
if(condition == 1)
  return await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new SampleLuisDialog());
else
  return await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new SimpleIDialog());
```

The issue is:
When it satisfies 2nd condition, it executes the logic within `SimpleIDialog`. When it satisfies the 1st condition instead of getting into the `SampleLuisDialog`, it again gets into `startAsync` of `SimpleIDialog`.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is only one condition here. Use a debugger and see what the value of `condition` variable is.

Comment: one condition only , when I said 2nd condition , I meant else part of it

Comment: OK, then still the other part of my comment applies. How do you verify that when condition is met, the else clause is being executed anyway? Try the debugger!

Comment: yes , it goes into else block but the doesnot hit any of the LUIS intents (i.e. any method within the LUIS dialog)

Comment: Well, it's an async method so it won't necessarily execute it right away. Have you tried putting breakpoints inside `SampleLuisDialog` constructor?

Comment: @suchismita did you find a solution to this problem? I have the exact same situation in my code. context.Done doesn't seem to solve the issue

Comment: No , I did not find any solution . I went ahead with having only LuisDialig and moving the conditions as conversationdata properties.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your first called Dialog, you will have to call Context.Done at some point. Before that, the User is "stuck" in that Dialog.

So before you start another Dialog, you will have to "Close" the first called Dialog.

Comment: agree . that works well if we have a root dialog and from within it we try to call few other child dialogs . But in my case, I am trying to call multiple dialogs from within the MessageController.cs